# How do I take advantage of FreeIPA centralized authentication in an LXC container under Proxmox?

Tags: lxc, proxmox, freeipa

I'd like to request assistance with an issue I'm having in my Proxmox homelab. I have a FreeIPA domain `lab.ads1031.local`, in which resides a user `ads1031` with UID `1000001`. I would like to log in as that user on an LXC container, running under Proxmox. The container's ID is `104`.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Placed these lines in /etc/subuid on my Proxmox host:

  ```
  root:100000:65536

  root:5000000:2500000
  ```
- Placed similar lines in /etc/subgid on my Proxmox host:

  ```
  root:100000:65536

  root:5000000:2500000
  ```
- Added these lines to /etc/pve/lxc/104.conf on my Proxmox host:

  ```
  lxc.idmap = u 5000000 5000000 2500000

  lxc.idmap = g 5000000 5000000 2500000

  lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 65536

  lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 65536
  ```

When I try to log in as ads1031 on the container, I can't. I see these messages in journalctl:

```
Jan 20 09:20:42 dragonegg login[91]: pam_sss(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost= user=ads1031
Jan 20 09:20:42 dragonegg login[91]: pam_sss(login:auth): received for user ads1031: 4 (System error)
Jan 20 09:20:44 dragonegg login[91]: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty1 FOR ads1031, Authentication failure
Jan 20 09:21:02 dragonegg dbus-broker-launch[66]: Activation request for 'org.freedesktop.login1' failed.
Jan 20 09:21:02 dragonegg login[91]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to create session: Could not activate remote peer.
```

I also took a peek in /var/log/sssd/sssd_lab.ads1031.local for clues, and found this:

```
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [krb5_auth_prepare_ccache_name] (0x1000): No ccache file for user [ads1031@lab.ads1031.local] found.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): Trying to resolve service 'IPA'
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): Status of server 'dragonutil.lab.ads1031.local' is 'working'
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): Port status of port 389 for server 'dragonutil.lab.ads1031.local' is 'working'
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [fo_resolve_service_activate_timeout] (0x2000): Resolve timeout set to 6 seconds
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [resolve_srv_send] (0x0200): The status of SRV lookup is resolved
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): Status of server 'dragonutil.lab.ads1031.local' is 'working'
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x1000): Saving the first resolved server
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [be_resolve_server_process] (0x0200): Found address for server dragonutil.lab.ads1031.local: [10.0.0.15] TTL 1200
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): Domain lab.ads1031.local is Active
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): Setting up signal handler up for pid [97]
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): Signal handler set up for pid [97]
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [write_pipe_handler] (0x0400): All data has been sent!
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [read_pipe_handler] (0x0400): EOF received, client finished
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [parse_krb5_child_response] (0x0020): message too short.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [krb5_auth_done] (0x0040): The krb5_child process returned an error. Please inspect the krb5_child.log file or the journal for more information
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [krb5_auth_done] (0x0040): Could not parse child response [22]: Invalid argument
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [check_wait_queue] (0x1000): Wait queue for user [ads1031@lab.ads1031.local] is empty.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [krb5_auth_queue_done] (0x0040): krb5_auth_recv failed with: 22
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [sssd[be[lab.ads1031.local]]] [ipa_pam_auth_handler_krb5_done] (0x0040): KRB5 auth failed [22]: Invalid argument
```

That, of course, prompted me to check in krb5_child.log, where I found this:

```
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [k5c_setup_fast] (0x0100): Fast principal is set to [host/dragonegg.lab.ads1031.local@lab.ads1031.local]
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [find_principal_in_keytab] (0x4000): Trying to find principal host/dragonegg.lab.ads1031.local@lab.ads1031.local in keytab.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [match_principal] (0x1000): Principal matched to the sample (host/dragonegg.lab.ads1031.local@lab.ads1031.local).
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [check_fast_ccache] (0x0200): FAST TGT is still valid.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [become_user] (0x0200): Trying to become user [1000001][1000001].
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [become_user] (0x0020): setresgid failed [22][Invalid argument].
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [main] (0x0020): become_user failed.
(Mon Jan 20 09:20:42 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[97]]]] [main] (0x0020): krb5_child failed!
```

Unfortunately, from here, I'm at a loss. I'd like suggestions on how to proceed.

I've tried adding `selinux_provider=none` to my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` [per this StackExchange post,](https://serverfault.com/questions/848620/freeipa-client-on-lxc-container-sshd-access-denied) but that post wasn't exactly about my issue, and the step didn't help.

[This thread over on servethehome.com](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/home-server-setup-and-management-help-needed.19674/) mentions that "Some minor editing of the container configuration file is necessary" but it doesn't seem to have provided the editing that is necessary. If that editing matches what I've done in `/etc/pve/lxc/104.conf`, then... it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. It was a bit of an ID10T issue, too.

Note that my user ID is 1,000,0001. I was attempting to map IDs of 5,000,000, which is greater than 1,000,000. Changing the 5 to a 1 fixed the issue.